# Using EnumWindowsProc on C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, service

I've writed this code inside a Windows Service with an Administrator rights account:

```
private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int MaxCount);
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

private static IntPtr shellWindow = GetShellWindow();
private static Dictionary<intptr, string=""> windows = new Dictionary<intptr, string="">();

private static bool _fEnumWindowsCallBack(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
{
    // It never execute this code
    if (hWnd == shellWindow) return true;
    if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    if (length == 0) return true;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
    GetWindowText(hWnd, builder, length + 1);
    windows[hWnd] = builder.ToString();
    return true;
}

public static IDictionary<intptr, string=""> GetOpenWindows()
{
    windows.Clear();
    EnumWindowsProc fEnumWindowsCallBack = new  EnumWindowsProc(_fEnumWindowsCallBack);
    EnumWindows(fEnumWindowsCallBack, 0);
    return windows;
}
```

But it does'nt work (never executes the _fEnumWindowsCallBack function).

Any idea why?

I'm using W7 x64, Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be because your Windows Service is not running in an interactive session.  There are no windows to eumerate.

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Minimum supported client
>
> Windows 2000 Professional **[desktop apps only]**
>
> Minimum supported server
>
> Windows 2000 Server **[desktop apps only]**